# Having trouble applying the C++ Subscriber application

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to retrieve some values from a published topic, and using that data in my main function. I can almost make it work with global variables, but I believe that is poor programming etiquette? Before I continue debugging my global variable solution, I would like to know if there is a simpler, more efficient way. Here is the callback function:

```
void chatterCallback(const sensor_msgs::JointState msg)
{
   for (int i=0;i<NUMBER_OF_JOINTS;i++)
    {
    std::cout << "The " << msg.name.at(i) << " is now at " << msg.position.at(i);
    std::cout << " moving with velocity " << msg.velocity.at(i) << "\n";
    }
}
```

I want to pass the data contained in the sensor_msgs::JointState to my main function, in order to start the program by ascertaining the robot's joint values. Also, I'm not sure the subscriber callback function is allowed to use sensor_msgs::JointState, rather than ConstPtr. The code works like this, though.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156226/having-trouble-applying-the-c++-subscriber-application/) by [paturdc](https://answers.ros.org/users/14791/paturdc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2014-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The subscriber signature works, but it is better to pass by reference, i.e. add `&`.

Depending on the program size, global variables might be fine.
A usual larger approach for something like this would be to capture the JointState message in a class where the code lies that uses this.
Within the class you can subscribe the callback in a member function and store the message in there.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1